# How to plot from adjacency matrix?

Tags: matlab, plot, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix and corresponding labels. I need to plot a network with weighted edges and different colors based on labels. I found there is `gplot` function in matlab, but it is not created weighted edges. Does anyone know any toolbox or function or something I can use?

Comment: Check the duplicate.  You can use `gplot` in association with weights to draw a weighted directed graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool called wgPlot by Mike Wu that will allow you to plot weighted adjacency graphs easily.

[wgPlot by MikeWu](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24035-wgplot-weighted-graph-plot--a-better-version-of-gplot-/content/wgPlot/wgPlot.m)

Note that the edges are not labeled textually, but by a color scale.

Comment: This is better than the duplicate I marked. Nice work.

Comment: It seems better. Actually, I have  a easy question. Does coordinates in this function refers indices ? If not how can I find coordinates of all points for a dataset?

Comment: Coord is a matrix of coordinates for your nodes, used to visually place the nodes on the plot. You can set it to whatever is most visually appealing.

Comment: I am getting this error for given example "S must be a scalar or a vector the same length as X." Does anyone know how I can fix?